# kali linux settings interface fails to load

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux

i have a Kali Linux 2.0 2017 64 bit ; what i discovered is that settings does not load anytime i press the setting option whenever i want to modify settings , all i get is just nothing. not even an error. i have tried to install the gnome-control-centre using apt; but i get this error:

```
olalekan@MW:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcanberra-gtk3-0 (>= 0.25) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.11.10) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcolord-gtk1 (>= 0.1.24) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgnome-bluetooth13 (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-10 (>= 3.11.90) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgrilo-0.2-1 (>= 0.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libnm-gtk0 (>= 0.9.7.997) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.33.92) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.13.91) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.13.91) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-user-guide but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-user-share but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gkbd-capplet but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: mousetweaks but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: policykit-1-gnome
                        Recommends: rygel but it is not going to be installed or
                                    rygel-tracker but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: system-config-printer (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: network-manager-gnome (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

after getting this error i think if i try to install all the depending and required packages independently, but as i try to install them one by one , i discover ; they are layered dependencies that each of the packages specified required ; and in some ways , some of the libraries are installed but apt keep claiming they are not going to be installed. any help is appreciated... thanks.

Comment: This pretty sums up your problem: 
`if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming`.

Kali Linux isn't a stable distribution since it's based on Debian Testing, which is a rolling release.

And rolling releases are as a matter of fact always breaking once in a while, no matter what people say about their strictly specific experience.

Comment: so, what shall i do now ; or does this mean the os must be reinstalled

Comment: You shouldn't use Kali Linux as a daily driver, consider Debian or Ubuntu 16.04.1 (LTS). Why do you want to use Kali Linux in the first place ?

Comment: i have been using it for almost three years now and i havent face this kind of error. i use it basically because it gives the required satisfaction i want. is there a way i can reinstall the gnome or something to solve the problem

Comment: In its current state, Debian Testing is still Alpha -so does Kali Linux-. If you really want to stay with Kali Linux, you'll have to wait for Debian Testing to get a proper gnome package. Besides, I'm still surprised that your Kali Linux install is still running; switching from 1.0.x to Sana then 2017.x isn't a peaceful path.

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) for reasons why you shouldn't be using Kali.

Answer (score 1):

1yr later but

```
apt-get upgrade gnome-control-center
```

Fixed on gnome-control-center 3.34.1. Plus, if this OS suits you I don't see a reason why you shouldn't use it daily if that is what you want, by this time you should be use to constant updates and upgrades I guess. If you decide to change I will recommend you Arch not Ubuntu.